# Searching a deep autoencoder example for dimensionality reduction

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, dimensionality-reduction, autoencoder

I want to configure a deep autoencoder in order to reduce the dimensionality of my input data as described in this [paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/science.pdf). The layer sizes should be 2000-500-250-125-2-125-250-500-2000 and I want to be able to **pull out the activation** of the layer in the middle (as described in the paper, I want to use the values as coordinates). The input data consists of binary vectors with a length of 2000 each.
Now I'm searching for a **working example** which I can use as a starting point. I already tried [DeepLearning4J](http://deeplearning4j.org/) but wasn't able to build a satisfying autoencoder. I would be thankful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at some of the tutorials over at [deeplearning.net](http://deeplearning.net). They have a [Stacked Denoising Autoencoder](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/SdA.html) example with code. All of the tutorials are written in [Theano](http://github.com/Theano/Theano) which is a scientific computing library that will generate GPU code for you.

Here's an example of a visualization of the learned weights on the 3rd layer of a 200x200x200 SdA trained on [LFW](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/). You can simply modify the SdA tutorial code linked above to get the same results.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) The example is running fine. Can you give me a recommendation how to feed my own data into the network?

Comment: Sure, upload some data to a Dropbox or a google drive and I can show you how to get your data in the right format.

Comment: That's kind. As mentioned my dataset consists of feature vectors with the length of 2000. In the tagged versions the last column contains a label (1-9) for the verification of the result. You can find the data [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6808526/4817.zip) Thanks!

Comment: What type of data is it? That will help me with visualization / debugging.

Comment: Each sample in the dataset stands for an article. Each position in the vector with a length of 2000 represents one of the 2000 most common words in all articles. In the binary version 'true' means that the word (which the position stands for) occurs in the article at least one time. The float values are calculated by (occurrence of the current word in the current article) / (maximum occurrence of a word in the current – thus a value of 1.0f stands for the most common word in an article. The labels are representing topics (overlaps between topics are possible). I hope this information helps :)

Comment: I also uploaded the complete (unlabeled) data [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6808526/all.zip). This might be more useful for the training.